# A problem with function deposit in bancor V3

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, pool

For the past weeks I've been studying solidity and trying to deposit on a liquidity pool without much success, so could you help me?

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts-v3/blob/master/contracts/network/interfaces/IBancorNetwork.sol";

contract Trying{
    IERC20 public dai;
    IBancorNetwork public bancor;

    constructor(){
        dai = IERC20(0xaD6D458402F60fD3Bd25163575031ACDce07538D);
        bancor = IBancorNetwork(0xeEF417e1D5CC832e619ae18D2F140De2999dD4fB);
    }
    function supply(uint256 _amount) external{
        dai.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amount);
        dai.approve(0xeEF417e1D5CC832e619ae18D2F140De2999dD4fB, _amount);
        bancor.deposit(address(dai), _amount);
    }
}
```

and I keep getting this error:

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from address to contract Token requested.
--> bancor/test2.sol:17:24:
|
17 | bancor.deposit(address(dai), _amount);
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^

also I'm doing this on remix, thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

Import the `Token` contract:

```
import "https://github.com/bancorprotocol/contracts-v3/blob/master/contracts/token/Token.sol";
```

and do:

```
bancor.deposit(Token(address(dai)), _amount);
```